# When adding view inside layout and when removing and re-adding IllegalStateException

Tags: android, layout, view, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

When adding view inside layout and when removing and re-adding, it throws like this.

```
The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first
```

Any Idea???

```
linearLayout.addView(view);
```

This line is called often(ie. everytime when activity resumes),
so i've added like:

```
((ViewGroup)view.getParent()).removeAllViewsInLayout();
linearLayout.removeView(view);
if(linearLayout.getChildCount()==0)
    linearLayout.addView(view);
```

But again same probs!

Comment: edit you question in a proper way, provide some more information plus code sample what you tried so far, to avoid unlimited -ve votes.

Comment: linearLayout.addView(view);

this line is called often(everytime when activity resumes),
so i've added like,
((ViewGroup)view.getParent()).removeAllViewsInLayout();
linearLayout.removeView(view);
if(linearLayout.getChildCount()==0)
 linearLayout.addView(view);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
((ViewManager)view.getParent()).removeView(view);
```

This Worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

if you create childs of layout  in activity dynamically and you go to another activity if you return you must remove views and recreate it with new informations.